# Moving layer when resizing window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML code

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="fixed">Logo</div>
</div>​
```

and then the following CSS code

```
#container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:right;
}

#fixed {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}​
```

When i resize the windows i want the fixed div to keep moving to the right when the edge of the window is at the begining of it.

Do you know any way of doing this with CSS, javascript or HTML?

I have created an example in jsfiddle you can view it in http://jsfiddle.net/alvarezskinner/kRrdb/ if you resize the middle bar you will see the fixed layer stays still.

Comment: Are you just trying to center the logo?

Comment: The only thing im trying to do is that the logo moves when the screen gest resized. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this does exactly what you want, but it at least gets closer. Change the `container` style to:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:right;
    max-width:400px;
}
```

Instead of moving the `fixed` div, this will just make sure that the `container` doesn't get wider than the page, thereby ensuring that the `fixed` div doesn't go past the left of the page. Will this work well enough?

Here is a fiddle if you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/kRrdb/2/

Comment: Adding min and max width is perfect as its only resizing the header, thanks so much for this solution

Answer (score 0):

If it is not acceptable for the container to resize, you could do something like this with javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var fixed = document.getElementById("fixed");

    var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var containerWidth = document.getElementById("container").offsetWidth;
    var fixedWidth = document.getElementById("fixed").offsetWidth;

    var overlap = containerWidth - winWidth;

    if(overlap > 0) {
        // prevent the element from moving off-screen
        overlap = Math.min(overlap, fixedWidth);
    }else{
        overlap = 0;  
    }

    fixed.style.marginLeft = overlap + "px";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kRrdb/4/

This could be made more concise.  I have expanded to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thats is also another solution, thanks all for your quick answers!

Comment: Actually this is an awesome solution, when the wrapper cannot be resized, in this case its only the header that is fixed so the other css option is enough, Thanks so much for this code though!